# ¿Cuál es la frase más adecuada para traducir "thin film" en el contexto de la mecánica de fluidos?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, ciencia, comparación-de-idiomas

Hace poco leía una respuesta traducida del inglés al español en algún foro en línea, cuando vi la frase "película delgada". No se refería a ningún cortometraje, sino a una lámina fina de fluido que yace sobre otro fluido o sobre una superficie sólida. En inglés se hablaría de la ["thin-film equation"](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thin-film_equation), aunque curiosamente este artículo no parece existir en otros idiomas. 
Sin embargo, no estaba seguro de que ese fuera el término idiomático, así que indagué en el asunto.

Wikipedia tiene una página sobre [la cromatografía en capa fina](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cromatograf%C3%ADa_en_capa_fina), donde la última parte de esta frase hace referencia a la capa de absorbente que se utiliza para esta técnica. Sin embargo, hay otra página sobre [las láminas delgadas](https://es.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%A1mina_delgada), pero principalmente parece tratar de los materiales sólidos. Al buscar los varios términos en Google, descubrí que "película delgada" (o fina) y "capa fina" (o delgada) tenían aproximadamente el mismo número de resultados, mientras que todas las formas construidas con "lámina" eran menos comunes. No obstante, esto no es definitivo.

¿Cuál sería la forma más correcta de expresar este concepto en español cuando se trata de los fluidos? ¿Película delgada, capa fina, lámina fina, u otra combinación?

Comment: Escoge una revista donde te gustaria publicar algun trabajo de este tema, y utiliza la terminologia mas usada en sus articulos.  // Estoy de acuerdo con lo que dices de *laminas*. // A mi en lo personal me gusta mas *pelicula* que *capa*.  *Pelicula* parece ser un termino tecnico, un termino mas precision, que *capa*.

Comment: @aparente001 - Jajaja, supongo que sí, pero que yo haya visto, muchas de las revistas científicas en español (¿la mayoría?) realmente están en inglés y solamente tienen los títulos y resúmenes en español. A lo mejor hablan de la "thin-film equation" y ya.

Comment: thin/thick film= **película fina y gruesa**.  delgada es un error de traducción. capa no es film, es **coating**, una capa de pintura.

Comment: Bueno, quizas sea asi, pero de ser asi me resulta interesante que "capa" parezca mas comun en las paginas que tratan de la ecuacion, y "delgada" tambien.

Comment: @Obie2.0 capa no es film. capa es coating. Me gano la vida traduciendo esas cosas al inglés. a thick film of oil on the sea: una película gruesa de petroleo en el mar. Puede haber: a thick or thick coating of something, or a thick or thin film of something.

Comment: @Lambie - No dudo de ti. Simplemente quisiera saber por que "ecuacion de capa delgada" tiene bastante resultados mientras que "ecuacion de pelicula fina" casi no existe.

Comment: Dialnet-DesarrolloAnaliticoDeLasEcuacionesGinzburgLandauPa-7000274%20(1).pdf//Condición
necesaria para películas finas d  ξ.//artículo muy serio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104115/discussion-between-obie-2-0-and-lambie).

Answer (score 5):

Para este tipo de traducciones viene bien la web del IATE (European Union Terminology), que se dedica a traducciones sobre terminología en ámbitos específicos, recopilando miles de traducciones e incluso catalogándolas en función de su fiabilidad.

En el caso de *[thin film](https://iate.europa.eu/search/standard/result/1580892976634/1)*, la web recoge para el ámbito *electronics and electrical engineering* la siguiente traducción:

> película delgada

Esta traducción está catalogada como "reliable" (fiable). Otras traducciones alternan el adjetivo *delgado* con *fino*, por lo que "película fina" también sería correcto. Lo que se mantiene en casi todas las traducciones es el término *[película](https://dle.rae.es/pel%C3%ADcula)*, y en mucha menor medida aparecen los términos *capa* o *lámina*. Curiosamente, en el ámbito *chemistry* aparece la siguiente traducción:

> thin film electrolyte
>   capa delgada de electrolito

En esta sí se usa la palabra *capa*, que para el caso de fluidos sí puede ser más adecuada.

Comment: Finalmente me decidí a buscar "la ecuación de capa/película/lámina delgada/fina", porque dicha ecuación más o menos define el contexto, y la opción que parece haberse escogido más frecuentemente es "ecuación de capa delgada".

Comment: ¿ catalogada por quién ? fina/gruesa porque sino tendría que ser delgada y gorda. jaja

Comment: @Lambie lo siento, no entiendo tu comentario. Y el IATE es una web oficial de la Unión Europea, con bancos de datos de traducciones de todos los países y usada por las instituciones de la Unión y por traductores técnicos como tú. Yo diría que es bastante fiable como referencia.

Comment: Ingenieria electrica no es el unico campo donde se estudian las peliculas finas. // Creo que @Lambie nos esta diciendo que si hablamos de *delgada* lo contrario seria *gorda* y eso seria un tanto absurdo. // En la fisica las peliculas finas son mas finas que las "capas."

Answer (score 3):

yo diría '`película fina`' o '`fina película`', o en vez de `película` `capa`. La segunda definición de `película` creo que se puede aplicar al caso (https://dle.rae.es/pel%C3%ADcula)

```
2. f. Capa delgada que se forma sobre algunas cosas o las recubre.
```

Recuerdo que en los libros de texto he visto '`fina película`' o '`película fina`'. `Capa` es más coloquial.

Comment: Bueno, pero ¿cuales de estas son mas adecuadas? Y particularmente, ¿cual termino se usa por l@s cientific@s cuando hablan de esa ecuacion?

Comment: si pones la frase tal cual te la traduzco, pero yo diría película fina

Comment: película fina es la mejor opción. Soy traductora técnica también y eso es el termino. capa es coating, película es film. fina c. gruesa